# javaFX helloworld jar cannot be ran on different platform

Tags: javafx

I am new to this JavaFX stuff and not sure if anyone knows what I did wrong. Here is the scenario:

1. On win 7, used netbeans 8 with jdk1.8.0_05 created a helloworld.jar
2. On win 7, java -jar helloworld.jar works fine
3. move the helloworld.jar to Redhat 5.8 and used the same version jdk1.8.0_05, java -jar helloworld.jar . and I see the following error

Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Answer (score 4):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.8 is not a [supported configuration for JavaFX in Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html).

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.x (and some other Linux variants) is supported.

---

MidoriKid provides a procedure to allow JavaFX to be used on a Red Hat EL 5.x system in his answer to: [running JavaFx jars on redhat 5.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438472/running-javafx-jars-on-redhat-5-8/).  Note that although the procedure can be followed, it is recommended that you uses more recent RHEL system to run JavaFX in a supported configuration.